# how to get the followings of any twitter account using tweepy

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

I have been using Tweepy for a while now. I am able to get number of followers for a handle with their handle name as well but not number of followings. I am using python3 and tweepy.
Can anyone help me out in this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `usr.friends_count`, where `usr` is a tweepy `User` object. A working example:

```
pub_tweets = api.home_timeline()
for tweet in pub_tweets:
    print(tweet.author.friends_count)
```

See https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/users for other information available in Twitter User objects.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response.
Can you also get me how to get those following's handle names as well?

Comment: You will need to iterate over all pages using http://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v3.5.0/api.html#API.friends_ids, and then retrieve user object for each id.